# tensorflow: check tensor rank

Tags: tensorflow, rank

I would like to check rank of tensor. Here is my code to do it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[0,1,0], [0,1,0]])
print(tf.rank(x))
```

It returns

```
Tensor("Rank_14:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

where `Rank_14:0` keeps growing. 
I expect it to return 2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rank_14:0` is the name of the returned tensor not it's value, you need to evaluate the tensor in a Session to get the actual value:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.rank(x))
```

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[0,1,0], [0,1,0]])
r = tf.rank(x)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
​
print("My tensor is: ", r)
print("The value of my tensor is: ", r.eval())

My tensor is:  Tensor("Rank_3:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
The value of my tensor is:  2
```

Comment: May I ask why the shape=()? Shouldn't it be (2,3)?